# Issue with an if statement for Tableau?

Tags: if-statement, tableau-api

```
`IF[Lead Time] <= 4 THEN "0-4" 
ELSEIF [Lead Time] <= 18 THEN "5-18"
ELSEIF [Lead Time] <= 39 THEN "19-39"
ELSEIF [Lead Time] <= 69 THEN "40-69"
ELSEIF [Lead Time] <= 108 THEN "109-160"
ELSEIF [Lead Time] <= 160 THEN "161-239" 
ELSE [Lead Time] "239+" END`
```

I keep getting the "expected END to match IF at character 0". Can anyone see what is wrong with my
code?

Comment: Did it solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

try using this

```
IF [Lead Time] <= 4 THEN "0-4" 
ELSEIF [Lead Time] <= 18 THEN "5-18"
ELSEIF [Lead Time] <= 39 THEN "19-39"
ELSEIF [Lead Time] <= 69 THEN "40-69"
ELSEIF [Lead Time] <= 108 THEN "70-108"
ELSEIF [Lead Time] <= 160 THEN "109-160" 
ELSEIF [Lead Time] <= 239 THEN "161-239"
ELSE "239+" END
```

Comment: Just to clarify AniGoyal's comment - its the use of quotation marks around the whole expression that was the issue.

Comment: @ARob4 I think the real issue was inclusion of fieldname after `ELSE`